# What datatype to use for a database column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a person table that will have columns such as first name and last name.

What is the best data type to use for these columns as they can be any length. Is there a rule of thumb when it comes to this?

I am using sql server 2008.

Comment: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***`I think it is highly unlikely someone to have a Firstname or Lastname more than 50 characters.`*** Datatype for string type with Unicode characters is `NVARCHAR` and you can limit both of them to `50 or even 100` would not make a much difference.

So you can say

```
Firstname nvarchar(50)
Lastname nvarchar(50)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Its as i thought. There's no magic datatype that auto expands as needed. This is my accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

Use [`NVARCHAR(N)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186939.aspx), where `N` is the largest number of characters you wish to support for the field.

If you expect that you will never have international names (say Chinese, Japanese, Hebrew and other scripts) than you can use [`VARCHAR(N)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx).

These are variable length fields that are suitable for string data of variable length.

Answer (score 1):

If any lenght can acceed 4000 for NVarchar or 8000 for Varchar you could use (N)Varchar(max).
But if this would be unlike you should prefer (N)Varchar(Yourlimit) because of perfomance issues.

[Ref1](https://sites.google.com/site/mrmbookmarks/msg/sql-performancecomparisonnvarchar4000vsnvarcharmax)  and [Ref2](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic647815-145-1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Varchar(50) data type and devide full name in to first name, middle name and l